# Laravel: select from multiple tables (preferently with ORM)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.5 with postgresql

I want to run this query (which actually runs in postgresql):

```
select table1.*
from table1, table2
where
    table1."table2_id" = table2.id
and
    table2."table3_id" = '$id'
```

I already have:

```
class table1 extends Model
{
    public function table2()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('app\table2', 'table2_id');
    }
}
```

.

```
class table2 extends Model
{
    public function table1()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('app\table1', 'table1_id');
    }
    public function table3()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('app\table3', 'table3_id');
    }
}
```

.

```
class table3 extends Model
{
    public function table2()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('app\table2', 'table2_id');
    }
    public function table1()
    {
        $table1="table1"
        $table2="table2"
        $table3="table3"
        $table2_id="table2_id"
        return DB::table(DB::raw($table1.', '.$table2))->
            select($table1.'.*')->
            where($table1.'.table2_id', "=", $propiedad_table.'.'.$table2_id)->
            where($table2.'.table3_id', "=", "'".$this->id."'")->get();
    }
}
```

At this moment I have 2 issues, table3->table1() throws an error, but in the description of the error have the same query I actually want and when I run it in postgresql it works, so idk the reason of the error, the second issue is if there is a better way to make this query using Laravel's ORM?

Edit:

The error I have is:

```
"SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid: "table2.id" (SQL: select "table1".* from table1, table2 where "table1"."table2_id" = table2.id and "table2"."table3_id" = '20e0cea9-eb58-4252-aa18-9e28a485d29e')
```

Comment: What error do you get, can you make a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rs = table1::with('table2.table3')
      ->whereHas('table2',function($q) use ($id){

        $q->whereHas('table3',function ($q) use ($id){
             $q->where('id',$id);
        });

      });
```

I'm bit unclear on you query hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was already trying to do something verry inefficient, thank you Ill solve this in a better way

Comment: Great I could be a help!